# How can I tell whether a model is embedded in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

So I have two models:

```
#app/models/rate.rb
class Rate
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :tiers

  field :name
  # other fields...

end

#app/models/tier.rb
class Tier
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :rate

  field :name
  # other fields...

end
```

Now according to the mongoid documentation I can do the following to figure out whether a model is embedded in another model:

```
rate.tiers.embedded?
=> true
Tier.reflect_on_association(:rate).macro
=> :embedded_in
```

But for both these approaches I need to know that Tiers are embedded in Rates. Is there a way that I can find out whether Tiers are an embedded model and then find out what model they are embedded in without knowing its relationship with Rates beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/Reflections%3areflect_on_all_associations) which:

> Returns all relation metadata for the supplied macros.

So if you say:

```
embedded_ins = M.reflect_on_all_associations(:embedded_in)
```

you'll get an array (possibly empty) of `Mongoid::Relations::Metadata` instances in `embedded_ins`. Then you can say:

```
embedded_ins.first.class_name
```

to get the name of the class we're embedded in.

Comment: I quite like this method, its more robust than the way I suggested, thanks!

Comment: I was looking at `M.associations` first but that seems to be deprecated, then the source of that method lead me to `M.relations` which doesn't seem to be documented. `reflect_on_all_associations` is at least documented.

Comment: Oh cool, yeah I found the documentation to be very limited so I did my own snooping by calling M.methods and then going through the methods that I thought might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I had hoped to find the answer here http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html but unfortunately not all the methods created in regards to relations were documented there. Here is how to do it:

```
# To get whether a class is embedded
Model.embedded?

# So in the case of Tiers I would do
Tier.embedded?
=> true

# To get the class that the object is embedded in
# Note, this assumes that the class is only embedded in one class and not polymorphic
klass = nil
object.relations.each do |k, v|
  if v.macro == 'embedded_in'
    klass = v.class_name
  end
end

# So in our case of Tiers and Rates I would do
tier = Tier.find(id)
if tier.embedded?
  rate = nil
  tier.relations.each do |k, v|
    if v.macro == 'embedded_in'
      rate = v.class_name # Now rate is equal to Rate
    end
  end
  rate.find(rate_id) # This will return the rate object with id = rate_id
end
```